# Как заполнить словарь сложной конструкции?

Tags: python, dict

Есть словарь вот такой конструкции:

```
{
 'DV': 
     {
       '1': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': ''},
       '10': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': ''},
       '100': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': ''},
       '101': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': ''}
     }
}
```

И есть список `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Как заполнить словарь, чтобы элементы этого списка были в полях value?
То есть ожидаемый эффект:

```
{
 'DV':
     {
       '1': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': '1'},
       '10': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': '2'},
       '100': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': '3'},
       '101': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': '4'}
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dct = {
 'DV': 
     {
       '1': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': ''},
       '10': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': ''},
       '100': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': ''},
       '101': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': ''}
     }
}

for e, d in zip(lst, dct['DV']):
    dct['DV'][d]['value'] = str(e)

print(dct)
```

Здесь мы на первой итерации берём пару `1` (первый элемент `lst`) и `'1'` (первый ключ вложенного словаря), преобразовываем число-первый элемент `lst` в строку и сохраняем его в ключ `'value'` словаря `dct['DV']['1']`. И так далее.

Вывод:

```py
{
    'DV':
        {
          '1': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': '1'},
          '10': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': '2'},
          '100': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': '3'},
          '101': {'dict_id': 'DV', 'tags': '', 'value': '4'}
        }
}
```

Но этот код будет работать, только если кол-во элементов в списке `lst` равно кол-ву ключей в словаре `dct['DV']`.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне только в этом случае и нужно, когда количество элементов равно